# Temporary Access to GCP Resources

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cloud, terraform

I am new to GCP but I have worked on AWS to provide temporary access to AWS Resources using AWS Cognito Assume Role API and Organzation pool of accounts and creating custom URL to access AWS Console.

I am trying to create similar type of solution for GCP as well. I want to provide access to users (500 Concurrent users will be there). Can anyone suggest what could be the best approach

Acc. to my R&D, Service Accounts can be used but some project limitations are there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [IAM condition](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/conditions-overview). The doc is interesting if you want to script the access. For a test, you can use the console

Start by adding or editing permission in the IAM page. Choose a role and then click on add permissions
[image]

Name your condition and choose the condition(s).

[image]

**EDIT**

You can use the [API directly for this](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/reference/rest/v1/projects/setIamPolicy)

You can also use the client library. There is no dedicated library for resource manager, you have to use the [discovery API](https://cloud.google.com/apis/docs/overview). Here [the description of the resource manager v1](https://cloudresourcemanager.googleapis.com/$discovery/rest?version=v1)

So, in Python, the code look like this

```
import googleapiclient.discovery
resourceManager = googleapiclient.discovery.build("cloudresourcemanager","v1")
result = resourceManager.projects().getIamPolicy(resource="<ProjectId>").execute()
print(result)
body={
'policy': {
  'bindings': [
    {
      'role': 'roles/storage.objectViewer',
      'members': [
        'user:myUser@example.com'
      ],
      'condition': {
        'title': 'expirable access',
        'expression': 'request.time < timestamp("2020-10-01T00:00:00.000Z")'
      }
    }
  ],
  'version': 3
  }
}
result = resourceManager.projects().setIamPolicy(resource="<ProjectId>", body=body).execute()
print(result)
```

*Note: you have to repeat the binding bloc for each role that you want to grant*

**BE CAREFUL**

In both case, you will set the IAM policy, it's an erase/replace of the existing policy on the project. By the way, one of the good practice is to perform a getIamPolicy (also in my example) before and to update the results before setting it.

Comment: Yes, but you will have to script this!! If the 500 users have the exact same restrictions, I mean, you want to apply the exact same condition at the same time on the same role, it's better to create a Google group, to put the 500 users in it and then to define the access and the condition  for only the user group.

Comment: No, 10 15 different set of permissions will be there, Can we define these set of conditions  using API? Because everything will be done on the fly using script

Answer (score 2):

GCP has [short-lived service account credentials](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-short-lived-service-account-credentials):

The process involves a caller which is either a Google account or a service account and who makes a request to create short-lived credentials for a second **service account**.

You can, for example, generate **OAuth 2.0** access tokens with specific permissions, that are valid for 1 hour.

**Note that **service account**s differ from regular user accounts in that they belong to specific GCP resources,like VMs, and are not part of the G suite domain. They also have no ability to login via browser.

Answer (score -1):

In GCP you can use Google Identity Platform to store user identity with user name and password. https://developers.google.com/identity

There are different types of identity store available and you can choose one of them from the list. From the Google Cloud->Identity Provider->provider list, select the option Email/Password (Attached screenshot[image]). You can use Google Firestore to save the user data.

Cloud Firestore (NoSQL) is a flexible, scalable database for mobile, web, and server development from Firebase and Google Cloud Platform.

I usually club this with Google Firebase and create the UI to accelerate the development.